# Как вернуться к вопросам/ответам, пропущенным при проверке?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, очередь-проверок

При проверке вопросов и ответов иногда пользуюсь кнопкой "Пропустить", так как не уверен, как правильно поступить. Пост в моей очереди проверки больше не появляется, но, очевидно, из списка постов для проверки не исчезает. В пользу эотй теории говорит тот факт, что количество непроверенных постов в хедере и на странице проверки различаются (на даный момент на моей странице проверки порядка 150 вопросов, а в очереди - чуть меньше 300).

**Вопрос: можно ли позже вернуться к рассмотрению тех вопросов и ответов, которые я пропустил, и которые ещё никто другой не проверил?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Вернуться к пропущенным проверкам можно

Правда, с большой вероятностью, они уже будут завершены. Инструкция следующая:

**Способ 1. Простой и очевидный**

1. Нажимать в браузере кнопку «назад», пока не вернетесь к нужной странице.

Способ 1.а

1. Открыть историю браузера
2. Найти нужную страницу

**Способ 2. Мощный и удобный**

Вероятно, требует привилегии [«Инструменты модератора»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

1. Открыть страницу [очереди проверок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/review).
2. Выбрать одну из очередей.
3. Выбрать вкладку «История»

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. В нижней части страницы нажать на ссылку «моя история проверок»

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Ещё раз пролистать страницу вниз и поставить галочку на «показать пропущенные проверки»

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. Теперь в списке видны пропущенные проверки и к ним можно вернуться. Если проверка не завершена, вы по прежнему можете принять в ней участие.

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подозреваю, что привилегия не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это кнопка скрывает вопрос исключительно от вас.

Да, вы поступаете правильно, эта кнопка предназначена для случаев, когда вы не можете оценить пост, например, из-за отсутствия знаний по предмету обсуждения.

Нет, вернуться к пропущенному ревью снова нельзя. Предполагается, что вы не изучите внезапно новый язык, например. Не беспокойтесь, скоро очереди рассосутся, и подобная проблема больше не повторится.

P.S. В моих очередях уже меньше сотни постов. Я пропустил не больше 5 постов, вроде. Вопросов и ответов, которые для оценки требуют глубоких знаний предмета, довольно мало.

Answer (score 1):

Было бы очень хорошо, если счетчик наверху не включал пропущенные сообщения. Или его показатель не per user, а per community?

Comment: Этот оранжевый индикатор показывает общее количество требуемых проверок на сайте. Он не подстраивается индивидуально для каждого участника (по [соображениям производительности](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar#comment758002_230726)).

Comment: @pizza понятно, спасибо.

Comment: @NormalHuman: спасибо, ценная ссылка.